# CASE in an update

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this UPDATE query

```
 UPDATE table SET 
 col2 = ( CASE WHEN ( col1 <> 0 AND col2 = 0 ) THEN val1 ELSE col2 END ),  
 col1 = ( CASE WHEN ( col1 = 0 ) THEN val1 ELSE col1 END )
```

My problem is that the script is set up in a way that one user could access this twice therefore `val1` would be in `col1 and col2`.

I want to check before adding `val1` if `val1` was already added to either `col1` or `col2` and if it is present in either of the columns then not to update the columns. 
val1 = a users ID
Currently this can happen, User 1 and 2 both have access to this update script so if either of them access it twice their ID would be placed in both col1 and col2 which is my problem.

```
id  col1  col2  
1   val1  val1     
2   val2  val2
```

I would like something like this instead

```
id  col1  col2  
 1   val1  val2     
 2   val2  val1
```

If val1 exists in either col1 or col2, no update is required.

Comment: perhaps you can give an example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   UPDATE table SET 
   col2 = ( if ( col1 <> 0 AND col2 = 0 ) ,val2 , if ((col1 = 0 and col2 <> 0) , col2 , if ((col1 = 0 and col2 = 0) , val1 , col2)) ),  
   col1 = ( if ( col1 = 0  and col2 <> 0) , val2 , if ((col1 <> 0 and col2 = 0) , col1 , (if (col1 = 0 and col2 = 0),val1 , col1 )) )
```